# group numbers in a column and sum in another colums in bash

Tags: bash, awk

would like to group numbers within user defined distance in a column and sum corresponding values in another column in a file in bash. 
Here is the sample file

```
D   seq 1876    A   seq 3802    31
D   seq 1877    A   seq 3803    104
D   seq 13691   A   seq 14117   15
D   seq 13694   A   seq 14120   65
```

so if user would define the distance to merge to 5 then sample output would look like

```
D,seq,1876-1877,A,seq,3802-3803,135
D,seq,13691-13694,A,seq,14117-14120,85
```

Comment: Your objective is not entirely clear. And, shouldn't the first line of the result be `D,seq,1876-1877,A,seq,3802-3803,135`?

Comment: what happens if you have a treshhold of 5 and the values 1, 4, 7 ? Do you group 1 and 4 and leave 7 alone ? Or do you group 4 with 1 and 7 ?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of **threshold** and **distance** in the question... anyone can explain a bit? threshold/distance of what?

Comment: MichaelVehrs, that's right, sorry for the typo. 
Lordofdark, if the values are 1,4,7 then they should be collapsed down to 1-7 as the distances between them values is less than or equal to user defined distance. Kent  distance or threshold is a user defined integer value that would be used to merge numbers that fall within the threshold or range when you subtract bigger number from smaller. Thanks

Comment: do you check the distance threshold for both columns 3 and 5?  Or, only one of them?

Comment: I believe that it would be nice to check the distance of both columns 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
awk -v d=5 '{
    a[NR]=$3;
    b[NR]=$6
}
(a[NR]-a[NR-1] > d || b[NR]-b[NR-1] > d){
    if(NR!=1){
        print "D seq",s"-"a[NR-1],"A seq",t"-"b[NR-1],c
    };
    c=$NF;
    s=$3;
    t=$6;
    next
}
{
    c+=$NF
}
END{
    print "D seq",s"-"a[NR],"A seq",t"-"b[NR],c'
}' file.txt
```

Where `d` has the distance value.

Comment: Thanks @7171u for your help